# Does a C# static class need to be instantiated?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new .NET developer. I would like to know whether a `static` `class` in C# needs to be instantiated? I created a `class` for a database connection:

```
public static class ConnectionHelper
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    }
}
```

I am instantiating this class in my C# application and getting the following error:

> The name 'ConnectionHelper' does not exists in the current context

The related code:

```
using (var cn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection())
{
    ...
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: where you defined the class ConnectionHelper?

Comment: Probably the calling code resides in another namespace. Make sure you add a `using` clause to your code so that the namespace that declares the `ConnectionHelper` is known at the call site. Alternatively use the fully qualified name at the call site (with the dots separating the namespace and the class name).

Comment: @Sebastian you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a namespace.

Add the namespace of your ConnectionHelper to your "using"-block.
For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ConnectionHelperNamespace;
```

If your static class defined in separate project, then add refernce to it in Project Explorer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx
and after that add the namespace to "using"-block.

Comment: I understand, But i am getting another error:

"The type or name space 'ConnetionHelper' could not be found (you are missing directive and assembly refrence)"

Comment: @amankhan At the top the file `ConnectionHelper` resides in your code says `namespace Some.Text.Here` that `Some.Text.Here` part is what you put in your `using` statement in the file you are trying to use `ConnectionHelper` in.

Comment: using ConnectionHelper;

but getting error:

The type or name space 'ConnetionHelper' could not be found (you are missing directive and assembly refrence)

Comment: Post pls what is written between "using"-block and `public static class ConnectionHelper
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    }
}`

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;


public static class ConnectionHelper
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    }
}

Comment: i am using both classes in root/administration dir. should i define path in using namespace?

Comment: change it to this: `using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Data.SqlClient; using System.Configuration; using System.Data; namespace ConnectionHelp {public static class ConnectionHelper { public static SqlConnection GetConnection() { return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString()); } } }`. And then in the class where you use ConnectionHelper add in using-block `using ConnectionHelp;`

Comment: same error: "Error 30 The type or namespace name 'ConnectionHelp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Dropbox\Public\tom\development\administration\login.aspx.cs 7 7 D:\...\development\
"

Answer (score 3):

No, a `static class` does not need to be instantiated. It **cannot** be instantiated, that's the point of the `static` keyword in class declaration.

You are not instantiating it, either. What you do is call a static method from a static class. And that's fine. But instantiating a class requires the `new` keyword.

You are probably missing a `using`-directive at the top of your file to make it compile.

Comment: you are right? Kindly let me know how to add directive at top?

Comment: What is the namespace of your ConnectionHelper class? If the name is not the same as the namespace name of the part of code where you are using the class, you need to put a "using namespacename;" on top of your file with the other usings.

Comment: namespace is same of file name, you can see in my question.

Comment: You need to post more code, we cannot guess the error from what you did not show.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by removing the satic in "public static class":

```
public class ConnectionHelper
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());
    }
}
```

It will work, but before being added some non-static attributes or methods, the instance can do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Classes create stateful objects - on which we perform various operations. For this we have to declare and instantiate objects.

`static` classes / methods are meant to be stateless. Mostly we just want `static` methods to **receive certain parameters**, **perform operation** and **return values / status**.

They are not supposed to store any intermediate results for which we need class data members.

So, simply-put, `static class` is not instantiated!

Comment: Why i am getting error to using the following:
using ConnectionHelper;
<br>

Error 32 The type or namespace name 'ConnectionHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)